# am actually configuring django on command prompt..... installed pip, python and django but whenever i run manage.py it raises an import error?

Tags: django

PS C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller> python .\manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller\manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller\manage.py", line 22, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller\manage.py", line 13, in main
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate
virtual environment?
PS C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller> python .\manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller\manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller\manage.py", line 22, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller\manage.py", line 13, in main
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a
virtual environment?
PS C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller> python .\manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller\manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller\manage.py", line 22, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\Ileri\Desktop\java basics\reactdjango\music_controller\manage.py", line 13, in main
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a
virtual environment?

Comment: How are you running django, is it within a virtualenv or without. Cases like this occur when virtualenv is not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have multiple python versions installed on your machine, Try  `python -m pip install django` and then run it again